# Splitting an array by performing an arithmetic function in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array in Ruby like `[3,4,5]` and I want to create sub-arrays by diving or multiplying. For example, I want to multiply each number in the array by 2, 3, and 4, returning `[[6,9,12],[8,12,16],[10,15,20]]`

After that, what's the best way to count the total number of units? In this example, it would be 9, while `array.count` would return 3.

Thanks

Comment: It's not at all clear from your example whether the multipliers are the array values themselves, or are an arbitrary other set of values. As for the count, it should be number of elements in the array times number of elements you intend to scale by: 3 * 3 in your example.  If the multipliers are the array values, that would make it array.length**2.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the array be divided into 3 sub-arrays like `[[9,12,15], [12,16,20], [15,20,25]]`, or can it be like `[9, 12, 15, 12, 16, 20, 15, 20, 25]`?

Comment: @pjs I fixed it to be more clear.

Comment: @Cupcake, I guess it doesn't really matter. After I get the array, I need to loop through all the elements anyways so it will get rid of the `flatten` step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it convenient to use matrix operations for this, particularly if it is one step among several involving matrices, vectors, and/or scalars.

**Code**

```
require 'matrix'

def doit(arr1, arr2)
   (Matrix.column_vector(arr2) * Matrix.row_vector(arr1)).to_a
end

def nbr_elements(arr1, arr2) arr1.size * arr2.size end
```

**Examples**

```
arr1 = [3,4,5]
arr2 = [3,4,5]

doit(arr1, arr2)
  #=> [[ 9, 12, 15],
  #    [12, 16, 20],
  #    [15, 20, 25]]

nbr_elements(arr1, arr2)
  #=> 9

doit([1,2,3], [4,5,6,7])
  #=> [[4,  8, 12],
  #    [5, 10, 15],
  #    [6, 12, 18],
  #    [7, 14, 21]]

nbr_elements([1,2,3], [4,5,6,7])
  #=> 12
```

**Alternative**

If you don't want to use matrix operations, you could do it like this:

```
arr2.map { |e| [e].product(arr1).map { |e,f| e*f } }
```

Here's an example:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [4,5,6,7]

arr2.map { |e| [e].product(arr1).map { |e,f| e*f } }
  #=> [[4,  8, 12],
  #    [5, 10, 15],
  #    [6, 12, 18],
  #    [7, 14, 21]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't vote it up because my rep is still too low, but this answers it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I could think of was:

```
[3,4,5].map { |v|
    [3,4,5].map { |w|
        w * v
    }
}
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way.

As for the count you can use `flatten` to turn it into a single array containing all the elements.

```
[[9, 12, 15], [12, 16, 20], [15, 20, 25]].flatten
 => [9, 12, 15, 12, 16, 20, 15, 20, 25]
```

Comment: I like this answer a little better than the accepted one. It's a little shorter and easier to understand.